# need help withself reference loop when serialize linq

Tags: json, serialization

I know this question was asked before but I couldn't find any solution for my issue.
I am developing a WebAPI with more than 10 Controllers which their methods access a server DB.
I am using Linq2SQL to write the queries and using Json to serialize the return to send it back to my application.
The problem is no matter how simple is the query it returns the self reference loop when serialize and this is happening in all controller methods. See one example below:

var retitems = dtcxapi.ListItems.AsQueryable()
.Where(i => i.IsActive == true && i.ListName.ToLower() == listName.ToLower()).ToList();
where dtcxapi is my DataContext and ListItems is my table.
When serialize it shows: Self referencing loop detected with type 'BV.IMSWEBAPI.User'. Path '[0].User1.Users1'.

But as I said this error will occur for any query in any controller methods. I tried already to use the ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore in mWeb config but it didn't fix.

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only true way to fix this is to not return your Linq objects and instead return a DTO/Model that is not tied to your database. If you are returning your database objects, you will always run into self referencing loops because of Navigation properties.

You haven't mentioned if you are using .NET Core or .NET Framework, but if it's Core, it won't use web.config at all and instead you should modify your startup method :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

But again, this is a bandaid, the correct solution is to use DTOs

More info : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/